# Good projections for Middle East and North Africa in D3?

Tags: coordinate-system, d3, middle-east

I'm a data visualizer who's mostly worked with US data, and I'm familiar with AlbersUSA project. However, I'm going to be doing a series of graphics on the Middle East. Any suggestions or interesting [bl.ocks](http://bl.ocks.org/) you've come across?

Answer (score 4):

So [Albers Equal Area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albers_projection) isn't just for use in the US. While it's mostly used here, you can change the center and parallels to reflect anywhere in the world. In this case, the Middle East.

You can do that in d3 by changing the center when you're defining the projection. It would look something like this:

```
var projection = d3.geoAlbers()
    .rotate([*Rotation appropriate for your AOI*])
    .center([*Center appropriate for your AOI*])
    .parallels([*Parallels appropriate for your AOI*])
```

When you put in your data, you should be able to manipulate d3 to display your GeoJSON how you would like.